# how to replace jaydebeapi package with python ibm_db package when sslConnection is used

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I am able to connect db2 database using jaydebeapi python 3.7 package which requires ssl connection. Below is the connection string:

```
connection_string='jdbc:db2://%s:%s/%s:sslConnection=%s;sslTrustStoreLocation=%s;sslTrustStorePassword=%s' % (dsn_hostname, dsn_port, dsn_database, ssl_connection, ssl_trust_store_location, ssl_trust_store_password)
```

I need to use python

> ibm_db package

instead but I am not finding any information on using it with ssl trust store.

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question concerns configuration and is not about programming.

The ibm_db module for python uses the CLI (call level interface) , a non-java interface supplied by a Db2 driver, unlike java based tools which use jdbc instead.

You can choose to connect with TLS/SSL either with a manually created truststore, or with a dynamically-created truststore.

The latter requires a recent Db2-client on your workstation (higher than Db2 v10.5 fixpack 5) and special configuration settings, and assumes that only a single certificate file is required and is available in ARM format.

For IBM cloud, the relevant documentation is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_cli_and_odbc_applications.html).

To avoid manually creating a truststore, use connection keywords SSLServerCertificate=fully-qualified-path-to-ARM-file and SecurityTransportMode=SSL.  Lookup the online [Db2 knowledge centre](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.clpplus.doc/doc/c0060762.html) for details. This is the easiest option.

To use a truststore, it will be a different store than the one used by java, and may require the additional software installation of the IBM Global Security Kit (GSK), followed by its configuration. This is the old way of using SSL with Db2 and has been superceded by the dynamic-truststore method above. IBM documents this in the Db2 knowledge centre [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0053518.html).

Comment: I tried using gsk but failed:
keytool -list -v -keystore ibm-truststore
keytool -export -alias cacert -keystore db-truststore -file cert.arm
gsk8capicmd_64 -keydb -create -db "dbclient.kdb" -pw "passw0rdpw0" -stash
gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -add -db "dbclient.kdb" -pw "passw0rdpw0" -label "dbcert" -file "/ssl_directory_name/ssl/cert.arm" -format ascii -fips
db2 update dbm cfg using SSL_CLNT_KEYDB /ssl_directory_name/ssl/dbclient.kdb
Error:
configuration parameter was not updated because the specified 
value is not valid.Specified value: "0".Configuration parameter name:
"fcm_buffer_size"

Comment: Don't add new facts via comment thread, because they are not easily  readable . Do edit the question instead, and use the formatting to make it easy to read. Also explain if you tried easier option first.